# Grouping Taxonomy terms by their parents

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have a Taxonomy Vocabulary for all types of cars. It has the following hierarchy:

```
Main Brand 1
- Sub0
- Sub1
- Sub3
Main Brand 2
- Sub1
- Sub2
```

and so on...

I want to have a webpage that displays the sub items when the main brand is selected.

Also, is there a way when assigning a specific value for the main brand field in my content type, for another field to appear populated by the sub brands of the main field?

Answer (score 6):

Hope I'm not too late, but maybe others will find this helpful...

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this is what you do:

1. Add *two* taxonomy name fields to your view display—one excluded from display, the other not.
2. Add a relationship of "Taxonomy term: Parent term" (under Advanced) and then attach it to the field excluded from display.
3. Under in the view's format settings, group by the excluded field with the relationship.

Note: If the parent terms are being printed twice (not just as group headers), make sure you excluded the field with the relationship and check "Require this relationship" in the relationship settings.

I don't know if this works with tertiary+ levels. Probably not. In which case there's most likely a module.

Answer (score 3):

First part of your question can be achieved by using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

- You will have to create a display that displays all level 1 terms (filter on parent term = 0)
- Then create another display with a contextual filter on parent term.
- Make sure the terms from display 1 link to "view-path-display-2/parent-term"

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Robin..

I've done the first step >>> Created view with level 1 terms...

Can you please Elaborate on the next 2 steps you mentioned

Thanks again

Comment: Add a new display in your view and remove the parent filter. The add a "contectual filter" under "Advanced". This will make your view available at "path-display2/your-parent-term". Views will pick up the 2nd param (your-parent-term) and ad a condition to the views query "where parent_term = your_parent_term". So only the terms who have  "your_parent_term" as parent will be displayed.

Comment: I'm new at this, so bare with me...
If you can give me a step by step I will really appreciate it

Thanks Again

Comment: here is a screenshot of the contextual filter you have to add: http://prntscr.com/670u89