# How to display all the terms of a vocabulary with a list of the items associated to the term below in a view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

In a view in D8, I want to achive something like :

```
term 1
-item 1
-item2
term 2
-item 3
-item 4
term 3
- item 5
- item 6
```

Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Found the solution here : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155116/views-page-list-of-all-content-grouped-by-taxonomy-term

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for a glossary view.  There are many tutorials on how to do this, ex: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/glossary/

... after rereading, you may actually be looking to create a view of all terms in that is grouped by parent id. There are different ways to do this. Take a look at:

- [Grouping Taxonomy terms by their parents](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/148885/grouping-taxonomy-terms-by-their-parents)
- https://www.konordo.com/blog/show-taxonomy-terms-grouped-taxonomy-parent

These talk about D7, but the same should work in D8